# Can a master prevent their slave from getting married?

Tags: fiqh, slavery

As we know, in Islam, slavery has never been abolished, suppose a slave wants to get married to satisfy his or her desires in halal, what is ruling about this, can the master prevent him or her?

Comment: Regarding the non-abolition of slavery, [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=84431) describes it as "if the world now gets together and forbids slavery, Islam will welcome such an initiative as it fits into its aims and objectives. It is lawful for the Muslim leader to sign a convention forbidding slavery."  But continues "If the world returns back to enslaving prisoners of war, Muslims will treat their enemies equally."

Comment: As far as I know, what has not been declared explicitly haraam in the texts cannot just be declared as haram by anyone, to take an example, the second khalifa of Islam, Umar RA while being a muslim leader declared that woman should lower their dowry but had to immediately changed his statement after a woman from the audience told that the Quran give woman the right to set their dowry

Comment: Relevant, but doesn't answer the question: Allah says to walis\owners that [[24:32](https://quran.com/24/32)]: ***And marry [as in arrange the marriage of] ... the  righteous among your male slaves and female slaves***. This is interpreted as a recommendation and not an obligation. Further, a slave can not marry without the permission of his\her owner. This stems from for example [[4:25](https://quran.com/4/25)]: ***marry them with the permission of their people*** and [[16:75](https://quran.com/16/75?translations=84)]: ***a slave, owned, who has no power over anything***.

Comment: it helps thanks, probably, views from the 4 imams might help also if anyone is aware of them